# Adding a new column to the existing data frame from another data frame if they have similar ID

Tags: r

I have a list of 16 data frames with 65 rows and 225 columns (e.g., df1). I want to add a column (Time) to all of these data frames from the column of another data frame (e.g., df2) with 265 rows and 4 columns when they have the match ID.
Let clarifying the problem by the following reproducible example.

```
df1<-data.frame(Id=c("TC-02-1998-Alex","TC-08-2003-Ben","TC-27-2006-Tom","TC-27-2007-Shan"),
                kps=c(70,90,100,80))

df2<-data.frame(Id=c("TC-02-1984","TC-02-1998","TC-06-1999","TC-08-2003","TC-27-2006","H-10","TC-27-2007","W1-10-112"),
                Time=c(188,223,1455,667,45,432,89,2311))
```

Eventually, I want to achieve the data frame like result_df1:

```
result_df1<-data.frame(Id=c("TC-02-1998-Alex","TC-08-2003-Ben","TC-27-2006-Tom","TC-27-2007-Shan"),
                   kps=c(70,90,100,80),Time=c(223,667,45,89))
```

I tried this code, however, it did not work.

```
df1_str<-substr(df1[,1],1,10)
df2_str<-substr(df2[,1],1,10)

for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  
if (df1_str==df2_str){
  df2$time<-df1$Time[i]
  
}
}
```

I appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `regex_left_join` and it is much simpler and can work for various cases i.e. even if the strings vary at the beginning or end

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(df1, df2)%>% 
    select(Id = Id.x, kps, Time)
#               Id kps Time
#1 TC-02-1998-Alex  70  223
#2  TC-08-2003-Ben  90  667
#3  TC-27-2006-Tom 100   45
#4 TC-27-2007-Shan  80   89
```

---

If it is a `list` of `data.frame`s, we can do this with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(list_df, regex_left_join)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do for one dataframe :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(Name = substring(Id, 12),
         Id = substring(Id, 1, 10)) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'Id')


#          Id kps Name Time
#1 TC-02-1998  70 Alex  223
#2 TC-08-2003  90  Ben  667
#3 TC-27-2006 100  Tom   45
#4 TC-27-2007  80 Shan   89
```

Or using base R :

```
merge(transform(df1, Name = substring(Id, 12),
                     Id = substring(Id, 1, 10)), df2, by = 'Id')
```

For your list of dataframes you can use `lapply`/`map` to apply the same function :

```
list_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {
           x %>%
            mutate(Name = substring(Id, 12),
                   Id = substring(Id, 1, 10)) %>%
           left_join(df2, by = 'Id')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `separate` + `select` or `separate` + `unite`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  separate(Id,c("d","Name"),"-(?=[A-z])",remove = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(df2, by=c(d="Id"))%>%
  select(-d,-Name)

               Id kps Time
1 TC-02-1998-Alex  70  223
2  TC-08-2003-Ben  90  667
3  TC-27-2006-Tom 100   45
4 TC-27-2007-Shan  80   89

df1 %>%
  separate(Id,c("Id","Name"),"-(?=[A-z])") %>%
  left_join(df2,by = "Id")%>%
  unite("Id",Id, Name,sep = "-")
               Id kps Time
1 TC-02-1998-Alex  70  223
2  TC-08-2003-Ben  90  667
3  TC-27-2006-Tom 100   45
4 TC-27-2007-Shan  80   89
```